# Why did languages such as shell scripting and perl use $ in front of variable names?

Tags: coding-style, language-design, language-features

## Context

Perhaps I'm just use to C-esque styled languages but having a sigil in front of a variable (e.g. `$VAR`) always strikes me as weird.

## Question

Why do some languages such as Perl and shell scripting have sigils in front of the variable names?

I can see it making sense for older languages like Basic (1960s) where the interpreter might not be smart enough to know what type of variable we are referring to. Looking at C in the 1970s, we see that is all but gone. In the 1980s, shell and Perl appeared and use the sigil notation yet Tcl, Erlang and others like C++ don't. In the 1990s, we see Python and Ruby not having sigils at all. Perhaps they do exist, but I haven't seen a recently developed programming language use sigils. I have, however, seen language do other stuff such as decorators from python `@staticmethod` that can look like sigils but is used in a different context.

I don't code a lot in Perl but for bash, `printf` is a function and wrapped in a command substitution, `$(printf ...)` creates sprintf from C. With both of these options, I don't see gains of say using `"This ${magic}String"` over `printf "This %sString" "$magic"` especially when strings get really long. Similarly, `${#STR}` is confusing, especially to newer programmers that don't know what that piece of code does, whereas `len str` is easier to read. Perhaps I'm just nitpicking over something that doesn't matter and everyone just accepts and moves on.

Comment: For one, it eliminates conflicts between variable names and language reserved words.   It also makes it very clear what is a variable and what is not when reading code.  For languages with very few variable types, like perl, it even tells you the (guaranteed) type of the variable.

Comment: To make also the difference between the name (x as a symbol or string) of a variable and the value of a variable ($x the value of x)

Comment: In the case of shell scripts, the name of an executable file is also the command to run it.  Given the token **foo** in a shell script, it's really helpful to know if it's a variable or command name.

Comment: if you type 'ls foobar' at a command prompt, how else would bash know whether `foobar` is a variable or the name of a `file`, particularly in the case where both a variable and a file of that name exists?

Comment: @BryanOakley As for filenames you could add ./ to clarity that it's a file. 
As for commands, you could use $(cmd) to clarify them but I suppose that in other languages, it's not as clear, or requires some call like cmd(...). Both require more typing which I suppose takes more effort than a sigil character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the 1990s, we see Python and Ruby not having sigils at all.

Ruby doesn't have sigils? Ruby is the king of sigils!

- `$` is a global or pseudo-global variable,
- `@` is an instance variable,
- `@@` is a class hierarchy variable, and
- (not technically a sigil, but similar in spirit) an uppercase letter is a constant variable.

And in the two cases where there *isn't* a sigil, there is an ambiguity between variables and methods:

```ruby
foo
```

is that a method call or a variable? Ruby says: both! If it has *parsed* (*not* executed) an assignment before, it assumes, it's local variable, otherwise it assumes, it's a method call. So:

```ruby
foo # method call

if false
  foo = 42 # it doesn't matter that this isn't executed, only parsed
end

foo # local variable
# => nil
# un-initialized local variables evaluate to nil
```

Okay, and what if I want to call a method named `foo` now? Well, I need to make it clear to Ruby that I intend to call a method:

```ruby
foo() # pass an argument list, only methods can take arguments

self.foo # provide an explicit receiver, however doesn't work for private methods
```

This poses another problem: if I have a function assigned to a variable, how do I call that function? I can't do it with `foo()`, because that calls a method named `foo`, I have to say `foo.()`.

For constants, the situation is similar. `Foo` is always interpreted as a constant, in order to treat it as a method call, you have to say `Foo()` or `self.Foo`.

In Python, this ambiguity is resolved by always requiring an explicit receiver for anything which isn't a variable, and always requiring parentheses for calls. So, a local variable is always `foo`, a method call is always `self.foo()`, and calling a function stored in a local variable is always `foo()`. An instance variable is always `self.foo`.

ECMAScript solves it by having a single namespace for functions and variables, so that it is impossible to have both a function and a variable named `foo`:

```ecmascript
let foo = 42;

function foo() {};
// TypeError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
```

Comment: I guess I should use RUby a bit more and learn about that.

Answer (score 5):

In shell, where you have shell scripts, with an environment that can be manipulated by the caller of the script, it's really really useful if you can distinguish between "this is a variable reference" and "this is text" without having to consult the environment.

If any "defined variable" would be substituted for its value, the following would not be safe in a shell script:

```
ls /tmp/*
```

Because if you wanted that to become harmful, all you would need would be to do the following:

```
ls=rm
export ls
```

So having some sort of distinct signal saying "yes, this is fetching the value of a variable" is very useful.

Perl (probably) got this from shell, but extended it to use various prefix symbols to denote data types, so `$foo` is a scalar variable, but `@foo` is an array variable.

Comment: Even more evil: `ls=rm; tmp="/";`

Comment: I don't believe this is one of the reasons variables are prepended with "$". Simply because you CAN replace commands with "alias". Example "alias ls=rm".

Comment: @user161778: Note that an alias is NOT inherited through the normal environment (thus the need to define them in .bashrc).